# Toggle and fade Images in a group

Tags: jquery, toggle, fade

I have two groups of images named with the following patterns:

Oranges1.jpg
Oranges2.jpg
Oranges3.jpg
Oranges4.jpg

Apples1.jpg
Apples2.jpg
Apples3.jpg
Apples4.jpg

On my page I have a div which displays a selection of images from each group:

```
<div>
<img src="Oranges1.jpg"/>
<img src="Oranges2.jpg"/>
<img src="Apples3.jpg"/>
<img src="Apples4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

What I want to do via jQuery is to toggle and fade the images in between the two groups. For example, when the page loads the images above load. Then, after 5 seconds, the image groups toggle, so "Oranges1.jpg" becomes "Apples1.jpg", "Apples3.jpg" becomes "Oranges3.jpg" etc e.g:

```
<div>
<img src="Apples1.jpg"/>
<img src="Apples2.jpg"/>
<img src="Oranges3.jpg"/>
<img src="Oranges4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

So, every 5 seconds the images change to the opposite group but with the corresponding image number.

Any ideas on the best approach?

Thanks!

Comment: `setInterval()` and `.replace()` is to be used with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
$('div img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('src').indexOf('Oranges') != -1)
        $(this).prop('src', $(this).prop('src').replace('Oranges', 'Apples'));

     if ($(this).prop('src').indexOf('Apples') != -1)
        $(this).prop('src', $(this).prop('src').replace('Apples', 'Oranges'));                 
});
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Thank you, see the comment I made on the answer by Spokey as I ended up combining both of your examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('div > img').each(function(i){
        this.src = (/Apples/g.test(this.src) ? 'Oranges' : 'Apples') 
             + (i+1) + '.jpg';
    }); 
}, 5000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akcW2/)

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I ended up going with a mixture of yours and LorDex's example's in case there were absolute paths in the URL:

Comment: setInterval(function(){
    $('div > img').each(function(i){
        this.src = (/apples/g.test(this.src) ? $(this).prop('src').replace('apples', 'oranges') : $(this).prop('src').replace('oranges', 'apples') );
    }); 
}, 5000);

Answer (score 0):

The formatting didn't come out very well in the comments, but the combination of the two answers meant I went with:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('div > img').each(function(i){
        this.src = (/apples/g.test(this.src) ? $(this).prop('src').replace('apples', 'oranges') : $(this).prop('src').replace('oranges', 'apples') );
    }); 
}, 5000);
```

Thanks to both of you!